# Nautilus only starts as root user

Tags: 10.04, gnome, nautilus, permissions, privileges

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit, and when I attempt to start Nautilus from the command line, it does not appear -- although a PID is generated. As `root`/`sudo` i can start Nautilus fine.

**One note:** I run e16 as the windows manager, so I do not use Nautilus to draw my desktop. However, even under this configuration, Nautilus used to run fine as a "regular" user.

The permissions for Nautilus are the same as the other packages in `/usr/bin`. I believe this is a Gnome issue, but I'm fumbling at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ nautilus --no-desktop
```

should do the trick.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Same symptoms: No GUI for Nautilus, but there is a PID. But thank you for responding.

Comment: It may help to add the "--browser" option.  You can use the "--no desktop" option with it, but that doesn't seem to make any difference when I use other window managers.  I'm not posting this as an answer because I've never used e16 and don't know if it'll work :)  Oh, and adding the directory path to the end of your command might help as well.